# WordPress - Auto add custom class for new and updated post

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to automaticly add custom class for each new and updated post. After X hours this class will be removed.

Can I do this easy way?

Thanks for each answer ;)

Comment: Yes, this is easy to do. Check out [the_time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_time). You can just add a conditional (if/else) to your post's container (probably a div or article, if HTML5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the loop do this:

```
$class = ''; 
$posted_date = the_date('U'); // Wordpress function for getting post date
$hours_after = $posted_date + (60*60*3) // 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 3 hours - change hours as needed

if(date('U') < $hours_after){
    $class = 'my-class-name'; // Custom class name
}
```

Then in your HTML you can just add:

```
<div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :)

But i use `get_the_modified_time`, better for me ;)

Comment: It's me again ;)

How to add class like this but to item menu when **page** was modified?

Comment: Just make sure it's in Unix time `get_the_modified_date('U');`

Comment: It is ;)

But where paste this code to works with page in menu? In functions.php?

I try add this: `function special_nav_class($classes, $hours_after) {
 $posted_date = get_the_modified_time('U');
 $hours_after = $posted_date + (60*60*48);
     if(date('U') < $hours_after) {
             $classes[] = "special-class";
     }
     return $classes;
}` but not work ;)

Comment: I create new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547512/wordpress-add-class-to-item-menu-when-page-was-modified